# error in submission to the journal of springer

Tags: overleaf, springernature

I need to submit my paper in springer format but in final step I got these errors. How can I fix them, please?
This is my packages:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
    
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bibentry} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{enumerate}
 
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stix,bbding,pifont,utfsym,fontawesome}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabu, colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
 \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} 
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{tabu, colortbl}
```

Comment: Your bib entry `schoellhammer2004lightweight` looks faulty.

Comment: don't load tabu (which doesn't work in current latex) twice, don't load xcolor  three times don't load lipsum in a journal submission or fontenc twice, booktabs twice...

Comment: Please edit your posting to show the entries `schoellhammer2004lightweight` and `husseindistributed` in ref.bib.

Comment: I fixed all the errors, Just this one, how to fix it,please? Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation for explanation.

Comment: @ayla - It's *not* an error message, it's a warning message. Best solution: don't use the `caption` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting two warning messages, *not* two error messages:

- The entry `husseindistributed` in the file `ref.bib` would appear to be missing the required `year` field.
- The entry `schoellhammer2004lightweight` would appear to be missing the required `journal` field.

Comment: Thanks @Mico, I solved all the errors just I have this one how can fix it please? Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation for explanation.